# Determining whether coin is biased or not

Tags: probability

I have n coins, where n-1 are fair and one is biased, showing tail on both sides. I want to ascertain whether the coin is fair by throwing k-times.  If I get k-times tail, I decide it is biased. The question is :

What is the probability that this way of determination is false?

W( determination is false ) C(biased coin) T(throwing T k-times)

The solution is :

> P(W) = P(¬ C,T) +P(C, ¬ T)

I am not sure why do we care for the probability of not getting tail with a biased coin. Why don’t we determine the probability of W like this:

> P(W) = P(¬ C,T) +P(C,  T)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong if you pick a fair coin and get tails $k$ times because you will declare it biased.  You are also wrong if you pick the biased coin and do not get tails $k$ times because you will declare it to be fair.  With your two tailed coin the second possibility cannot occur, but you might have a coin that shows tails $0.99$ of the time and use the same algorithm.  The equation you were given correctly states that chance that your decision is wrong.